# Always show project navigator when opening a new window in xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Are there some options somewhere where I can set the defaults, like the project navigator to show when I open a new window in xcode.

I have dual screens and I often double click on a file so I can keep the current file open in a new window, while moving to a new file int he current window.

However I want that new window to have the navigation bar, which I always has to add.

Can I set this by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode offers a way to use custom key bindings to perform several actions. You can find them in the Preferences pane.

You could use these bindings to display Project navigation, toolbar and more right after opening a new window.

[image: key bindings screen capture]

As you can see, I added a new action called "Display nav and toolbar", which  is binded on "cmd + opt + ctrl + N".

Now every time I use this combination keys, Xcode will show Editor, Navigation, and toolbar for the key window.